# monochromatic solution to $xy=z$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Is it true that for any $k \geq 2$, there is an integer $n=n(k)$ such that for any $k$-coloring of $\{1,...,n\},$ the equation $xy=z$ has a monochromatic solution?

Answer (score 5):

Some hints :

This is a simple modification of [Schur's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem) via an exponential.

[This document](https://dcg.epfl.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/GT-LectureNotes.pdf) from EPFL on page 35 contains a proof of Schur's theorem which you can adapt to your problem.